# How to avoid hitting same endpoint in ASP.NET Webcore

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to create filters in my webapp controller. I want to get items by category, id or location. But they all use the same method: HTTP with an int as a parameter. What's the most elegant solution to hit only the method I want?

Here's an example of the problem. This code obviously gets the "hitting multiple endpoints" error.

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetShiftById")]
        public ActionResult<Shift> GetShiftById(int id)
        {
            return _context.Shifts.Find(id);
        }

        [HttpGet("{locationId}", Name = "GetShiftByLocation")]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Shift>> GetByLocation(int locationId)
        {
            return _context.Shifts
                .Include(s => s.Category)
                .Include(s => s.Location)
                .Where (s => s.Location.Id == locationId )
                .ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your action headers:

```
        // url .../controllerName/GetById/3
        [HttpGet("GetById/{id}", Name = "GetShiftById")]
        public ActionResult<Shift> GetShiftById(int id)
        .....
         .....
         // url .../controllerName/GetByLocation/5
        [HttpGet("GetByLocation/{locationId}", Name = "GetShiftByLocation")]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Shift>> GetByLocation(int locationId)
```

Or instead you can change your controller header:

```
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    public class ShiftController : Controller
....
```

in this case your urls will be:

```
       // url .../Shift/GetShiftById/3
        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetShiftById")]
        public ActionResult<Shift> GetShiftById(int id)
        .....
         .....
         // url .../Shift/GetByLocation/5
        [HttpGet("{locationId}", Name = "GetShiftByLocation")]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Shift>> GetByLocation(int locationId)
```